# Getting Language for Non-Unicode Programs

Tags: c#

Anyone have any idea how to get the value of "Language for Non-Unicode Programs" in Control Panel Regional Settings programmatically using c#?

Already tried CultureInfo, RegionInfo and getting the default encoding using the Encoding object, but I can only get the Standards and Formats value or the main code page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GetSystemDefaultLocaleName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318122(v=vs.85).aspx) or [GetSystemDefaultLCID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318121(v=vs.85).aspx) (and its [P/Invoke declaration](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetSystemDefaultLCID.html))

Comment: The link isn't broken. It points to a page that says the content has been moved and has a link to the new location.

Anyway, updated the links.

Comment: Is there an API to change "Language for Non-Unicode Programs"?

Answer (score 1):

The [NLS Terminology](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319088(v=vs.85).aspx#Language_for_Non-Unicode_Programs) page in *Internationalization for Windows Applications* has the answer:

> An ANSI application should check the language for non-Unicode programs setting during installation. It uses **[GetACP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318070(v=vs.85).aspx)** or **[GetOEMCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318114(v=vs.85).aspx)** to retrieve the value. No function is supported to set the language for non-Unicode programs.

The `GetACP` function returns the ["ANSI code page"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#ANSI_code_page) (e.g. 1252 for english), while `GetOEMCP` returns the "OEM code page" (the code page used in the console, 437 for english).

[Code Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317752(v=vs.85).aspx) has more information about code pages in Windows.

Comment: Is there an API to change "Language for Non-Unicode Programs" for example SetACP()?

Comment: Not if you believe the "No function is supported to set the language for non-Unicode programs." statement:) You ought to at least ask a separate question if you're serious about finding a way to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894154/image-as-text-on-different-languages-for-non-unicode-programs

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, `Thread.CurrentUICulture` gets that value.