# How to get current language for non-unicode programs in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Language for Non-Unicode Programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217801/getting-language-for-non-unicode-programs)

How to get the selected "current language for non-unicode programs" of system in .net?

You can see the "current language for non-unicode programs" in the following path in Win7: 
 control panel -> Clock, Language and Region -> Regional and language options ->   Administrative(tab) -> Language for non-unicode programs

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There are lots of questions that have already been answered here; if search does not find something appropriate, you should also look at the "Related" sidebar on the right.

Comment: Yes, it's duplicate, but GetSystemDefaultLCID returns other location that country location, but it is not

Comment: [Getting Language for Non-Unicode Programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217801/getting-language-for-non-unicode-programs) contains no solution

Comment: It is the correct answer.  It is up to you to explain why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: GetSystemDefaultLCID and Thread.CurrentUICulture don't return needed locale.