# Getting language for non-unicode programs in VBA

Tags: vba

How do I get the value of "Language for Non-Unicode Programs" in Control Panel Regional Settings programmatically using VBA?

My VBA code contains Cyrillic constants, which get garbled if the Language for non-unicode programs is not Russian, so I'd like to advise the user to change the setting before trying to use the app.

See [Getting Language for Non-Unicode Programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217801/getting-language-for-non-unicode-programs) for a similar question for C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Declare Function GetACP Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub CheckANSICodePage()
    If GetACP() <> 1252 Then
        MsgBox "This application requires 'Language for non-Unicode programs' to be set to English " & _
               "in the Control Panel and will not function properly otherwise." & vbCrLf & _
                vbCrLf & _
                "Press OK to exit.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "MyApp"
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

From [NLS Terminology](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319088(v=vs.85).aspx#Language_for_Non-Unicode_Programs) page in *Internationalization for Windows Applications*:

> An ANSI application should check the language for non-Unicode programs setting during installation. It uses **[GetACP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318070(v=vs.85).aspx)** or **[GetOEMCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318114(v=vs.85).aspx)** to retrieve the value. No function is supported to set the language for non-Unicode programs.

The `GetACP` function returns the ["ANSI code page"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#ANSI_code_page) (e.g. 1252 for english), while `GetOEMCP` returns the "OEM code page" (the code page used in the console, 437 for english).

[Code Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317752(v=vs.85).aspx) has more information about code pages in Windows.

Comment: http://vb.mvps.org/samples/Locale/ has a nice module providing other information on the user's selected locale.