# Image as Text on different languages for Non-Unicode programs

Tags: sql-server, winapi, vb6, base64

A multi user program, written in VB6, saves scanned pictures and shows/displays them on `Image` control. Users can scan pictures and same and/or other users can view them. Pictures are saved in a Text column (datatype = `Text`) of SQL Server. Saving and showing pictures works fine as long as `Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative -> Language for non-Unicode programs` (say non-uni-lang) is English (United States) or probably the same on both scanners' and viewers' PCs.

When viewers' non-uni-lang is different then they can't view pictures, pictures get corrupted.

I have noticed that the Recordset receives different data/text on machines with different non-uni-lang. Base64 equivalent of the saved Text is same on PCs with different non-uni-lang but decoding them back to binary differs.

`GetACP` API can be used to get the value but i couldn't find any API to change the value. There is a registry key but it requires reboot to have effect.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to change non-uni-lang?
2. Is there any way, independent of non-uni-lang, to decode base64 back to
   binary?

**Edit 1**
Base64 Encoding

```
select cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("mytext"))', 'nvarchar(max)') from (
    select CAST(mytext AS varbinary(MAX)) mytext from (
        select CAST(ImageData AS nvarchar(MAX)) mytext from ImageTable where ImageID = 123
    ) t2
) t1
```

Base64 Decoding (Code by CVMichael)
https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?197891-CryptBinaryToString-(new-BASE-64-function-so-RESOLVED)&p=1166849#post1166849

**Edit 2**

Eliminated SQL Server. I copied base64 string in a text file, read it as byte array in vb6, decoded and made multiple conversions and it showed the image on English PC but failed on Arabic PC. Please download the working code from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jv0ELXvxhd9E0V6RhiqrexVyiunG9UE1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: change the column type from `text` to `ntext`

Comment: The `image`, `text` and `ntext` data types have been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2005. Ref: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) _IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead._

Comment: The base64 symbol set is entirely composed of ASCII characters and so not subject to user's regional language settings. If your base64 data is getting mangled by regional settings I'd suggest your program's base64 encode/decode routines have major bugs. Also, base64 expands the size of the data you're persisting by 33% (each group of 3 bytes is transformed to 4 characters), so you're wasting storage space by doing that.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It is not the base64 which gets corrupted. I receive the same base64 on PCs with different non-uni-lang. It is the decoded result of base64 which gets different on different PCs. This is what i asked, a way to decode a base64 back to binary which is not subject to non-uni-lang or at least forced decoding by passing the non-uni-lang as parameter.

Comment: @GuidoG Didn't work. Created a new table with an ntext column, converted and inserted existing data into new table as `CAST(myTextData AS ntext)`. Worked on Eng PC and didn't on Arabic PC.

Comment: How do you do the base64 encoding/decoding ? Can you show us that code ?

Comment: @GuidoG code shared

Comment: Casting from `text` to `nvarchar` to `varbinary` is probably what's breaking the encoding process. Casting from `text` to `nvarchar` converts a 1 byte/character encoding to 2 bytes/character encoding (UCS-2 by default, unless you're on a database with a Supplementary Characters collation in which case it's UTF-16), then casting to `varbinary` gives you a binary chunk that still has that 2 bytes/character encoding. e.g.: `'A'` (0x41) gets converted to `N'A'` (U+0041 or 0x41 0x00) which then gets converted to `0x4100`.

Comment: Were you just storing the binary picture data into the `text` column before now? That would explain the symptoms of user's regional settings affecting whether or not they could display the image. Clients would be treating the `text` column as text, naturally, so octets in the 0x00-0x7F range (US-ASCII) would be unaffected but octets in the 0x80-0xFF range are codepage-specific characters and would be affected by regional settings. On the SQL Server side try just `select cast(ImageData as varbinary(max)) from ImageTable where ImageID = 123` to return the data to clients as a binary blob.

Comment: You might need a separate db connection with `Auto Translate=False` in the connect string to prevent these images (binary data) in `TEXT` columns from getting garbled by the implicit ACP conversion happening at the database connectivity layer (e.g. ADO/OLEDB).

Comment: @wqw `Auto Translate=False` worked. Post it as an answer.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning added a sample code with base64 string, eliminating sql server.